# Spring Boot JUnit test beanFactory.getBean null pointer exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, reflection, nullpointerexception

I've a functioni'm trying to test via JUnit but I am not able to find how to overcome this issue:

in the service i have this declaration:

```
Warning_Log Warning_Log_FRAGMENT = beanFactory.getBean(Warning_Log.class);
```

I tried declaring the beanFactory object in the test class with the @MockBean annotation but i get a null pointer exception.

The cherry on top of the cake is that the function i'm testing is private so i'm using reflection to access it.

Do you know how the beanFactory(Warning_Log.class) can be implemented in the junit test function?

EDIT

the code in the service is the following:

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonFragmentRequestWarning_Log = new JSONObject();
        jsonFragmentRequestWarning_Log.put("messaggio", "Create Session Blocked [Assertion="+policy.getString("name")+"]|[flag_block_create_session="+gateway.flag_block_create_session+"]|[ApplicationName="+Request.getHeader("ApplicationName")+"]|[ErroreDaRitornare="+erroreDaRitornare+"]");
        jsonFragmentRequestWarning_Log.put("sanitize", false);

        Warning_Log Warning_Log_FRAGMENT = beanFactory.getBean(Warning_Log.class);
        
        String sFragmentResponseWarning_Log = Warning_Log_FRAGMENT.warning_Log(jsonFragmentRequestWarning_Log.toString(), httpHeaders);

        JSONObject jsonFragmentResponseWarning_Log = new JSONObject(sFragmentResponseWarning_Log);

    }
```

the beanFactory is autowired in the service like so:

```
@Autowired
private BeanFactory beanFactory;
```

EDIT 2
This is what i tried in the junit function resulting in a null pointer exception:

```
Field bf = clazz.getClass().getDeclaredField("beanFactory");
bf.setAccessible(true);
bf.set(clazz, beanfactory);
```

And beanfactory is declared as follows at the beginning of the class:

```
@MockBean
private BeanFactory beanfactory;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you provide a skeleton of the class that uses this line? Where do you call this line, from which method? How does beanFactory get instantiated in the class? In general beanFactory probably is an application context of spring, and  usually it doesn't really make sense to use application context reference in your business code...

Comment: @MarkBramnik Thank you for the quick feedback, I added an edit to the original question, if I need to provide more details please let me know.

Comment: Can you add the relevant code from the unit test as well?

Comment: @ErikKarlstrand i've added the junit code for i used to set the beanFactory

Comment: Even if the method you're trying to test is `private` there's no need to use reflection in order to access the `public` field. Currently your `@MockBean` is not being used at all.
Instead of using reflection, just use the `beanFactory` you've mocked.

Comment: @ErikKarlstrand I do not have public fields in the service and i can not add getters and setters

Comment: Sorry, I misread. However, since you have created a mocked instance that is the one that will be used by your class, provided that you've instantiated your class-to-be-tested correctly. My previous statement still applies in this case.

Comment: @ErikKarlstrand i'm sorry to bother you but do you mind giving me a simple example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say that you have the following class:

```
@Service
public class MyClass {

    @Autowired
    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    /*
     * Some more code
     */
}
```

And then you want to create some unit tests for that class, such as this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class MyClassTest {

    @MockBean
    private BeanFactory beanFactoryMock;

    @Autowired
    private MyClass myClass;

    @Test
    public void testMyClass() {

        // Since we have annotated our BeanFactory with @MockBean
        // this is now the instance that will be used by our class-under-test
        Mockito.when(beanFactoryMock.getBean(Warning_Log.class))
            .thenReturn(...);
    }
```

This is the general idea. If you have a field that is subject to dependency injection you don't have to use reflection in order to access it in your unit tests. The `MockBean` annotation will tell the IoC container to use your mocked class wherever it is being injected.

Comment: I appreciate the answer but that is what i've been trying to do and i get a null pointer exception

Comment: Are you annotating your test class with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`?

Comment: Yes i'am, while debugging i see in the service that the beanFactory is the mocked one but i get a null pointer at this line

String sFragmentResponseWarning_Log = Warning_Log_FRAGMENT.warning_Log(jsonFragmentRequestWarning_Log.toString(), httpHeaders);

Comment: If you inspect the variables while debugging it should be pretty simple to tell what is null. My money is on the `Warning_Log_FRAGMENT`. To fix it you need to instantiate it and return it when your `beanFactory` is called

Comment: Yes exactly, the mockBean works fine, it was the Warning_Log_FRAGMENT that needed some parameters? thanks a lot! i will accept your answer as solved!